# Curl error: Operation timed out

Tags: php, curl

I have the following fatal error when trying to use Curl:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught HTTP_Request2_MessageException: 
Curl error: Operation timed out after 30000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received in      
/usr/share/php/HTTP/Request2/Adapter/Curl.php on line 200
Exception trace    Function       Location
0                  HTTP_Request2_Adapter_Curl::wrapCurlError('Resource id #12') 
                   /usr/share/php/HTTP/Request2/Adapter/Curl.php:200
1                  HTTP_Request2_Adapter_Curl->sendRequest(Object(HTTP_Request2))
/usr/share/php/HTTP/Request2.php:959< in /usr/share/php/HTTP/Request2/Adapter/Curl.php on line 172
```

However, I can't see how to best debug it. There's no reference to any line of code I've written, only the `HTTP_Request2` and `Curl` modules. What's the best approach to try and resolve this?

Comment: have you tried debugging before and after the statements in your code that actually make the curl commands?  try and find the offending request that way?  from there you can try it command line, with the -v switch, and try and get more info that way.  possibly the URL has now 404'd.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Your curl gets timed out. Probably the url you are trying that requires more that 30 seconds.

If you are running the script through browser, then set the `set_time_limit` to zero for infinite seconds.

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Increase the curl's operation time limit using this option `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,500); // 500 seconds
```

It can also happen for infinite redirection from the server. To halt this try to run the script with follow location disabled.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
```

Comment: This still helped me 5 years later. Thank you!

Comment: 8 years and the answer is still helpful!

Answer (score 3):

I got same problem lot of time. Check your request url, if you are requesting on local server like **127.1.1/api** or **192.168....**, try to change it, make sure you are hitting cloud.

Comment: great, any solution except creating virtual host on local machine ?

Answer (score 1):

Some time this error in Joomla appear because some thing incorrect with SESSION or coockie.
That may because incorrect HTTPd server setting or because some before CURL or Server http requests

so PHP code like:

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_page);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url_page);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . "./cookie.txt");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . "./cookie.txt");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, session_name() . '=' . session_id());

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  if( $sc != "" ) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $sc);
```

will need replace to PHP code

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_page);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url_page);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . "./cookie.txt");
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . "./cookie.txt");
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, session_name() . '=' . session_id());

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false); // !!!!!!!!!!!!!
  //if( $sc != "" ) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $sc);
```

May be some body reply how this options connected with "Curl error: Operation timed out after .."

Answer (score 0):

```
$curl = curl_init();

  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "", // Server Path
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 3000, // increase this
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"email\":\"DarylBrowng@gmail.coh\",\"password\":\"markus William\",\"username\":\"Daryl Brown\",\"mobile\":\"013132131112\","msg":"No more SSRIs." }",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Postman-Token: 4867c7a3-2b3d-4e9a-9791-ed6dedb046b1",
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

initialize array index "CURLOPT_TIMEOUT" with a value in seconds according to   time required for response .

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//s.tk/meta/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post.

Answer (score 0):

In curl request add time out 0 so its infinite time set like CURLOPT_TIMEOUT set 0