# Google Cloud PHP Curl timeout

Tags: php, curl, timeout, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I met this error sometimes on some CURL requests done (adding CURL options directly in the PHP like CURLOPT_TIMEOUT change nothing, and i use SDK for most of them...) :

```
Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

The "0 milliseconds" is always here, never more.
Seems like an "internet down" and so, URL are unreachable.

Any idea about a possible Google Cloud configuration to do maybe ?

EDIT : in verbose mode i've got "Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache". And then it reconnect again.

Thanks !

Comment: It seems like your url request is being blocked by a firewall. Which urls are you trying to access with CURL. Are you able to access the urls from a web browser?

Comment: URLs in HTTPS of some web API. Exact same requests work most of the time ! But sometimes I got the timeout error...  And yes, after logged the URL wich get the error, I'm able to access to this URL with a browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add these options to your CURL code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
```

These options were suggested on: [cURL: Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485811/curl-operation-timed-out-after-0-milliseconds)

Comment: Thanks, already done and change nothing to the issue in my case.

Comment: See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501159/curl-error-operation-timed-out. It suggests setting the timeout value

Comment: Change Timeout value change nothing to the issue unfortunately... I always get this same error message.

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you try to connect from some other server ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally it was just the normal "error" before doing an update on the DNS cache. So CURL do the request then, can't access to the distant server because IP has changed and get "Hostname not found". Here, he get the new IP and doing again the request, with success.

So no issue !